# override relationship behaviour in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, relationships

Say I have three tables in a declarative fashion, `Parent`, `Child`, and `Pet`, in such way that

- `Parent` has a many-to-many relationship with both `Child` and `Pet`
- `Child` has a one-to-many relationship with `Pet`

The code for them is (using Flask-SQLAlchemy, although I believe the solution lives in the realm of SQLAlchemy rather than in Flask).

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))

    # many to many relationship between parent and children
    # my case allows for a children to have many parents. Don't ask.
    children = db.relationship('Child',
                           secondary=parents_children_relationship,
                           backref=db.backref('parents', lazy='dynamic'),
                           lazy='dynamic')

    # many to many relationship between parents and pets
    pets = db.relationship('Pet',
                             secondary=users_pets_relationship,
                             backref=db.backref('parents', lazy='dynamic'), #
                             lazy='dynamic')

# many to many relationship between parents and children
parents_children_relationship = db.Table('parents_children_relationship',
    db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parents.id')),
    db.Column('child_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('children.id')),
    UniqueConstraint('parent_id', 'child_id'))

# many to many relationship between User and Pet 
users_pets_relationship = db.Table('users_pets_relationship', 
    db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parents.id')), 
    db.Column('pet_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pets.id')),
    UniqueConstraint('parent_id', 'pet_id'))

class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    # parents = <backref relationship with User model>

    # one to many relationship with pets
    pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='child', lazy='dynamic')


class Pet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pets'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    # child = backref relationship with cities
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('children.id'), nullable=True)
    # parents = <relationship backref from User>
```

I would like to do something like this

```
parent_a = Parent()    
child_a = Child()
pet_a = Pet()
```

I can then do this

```
parent_a.children.append(child_a)
# commit/persist data
parent_a.children.all() # [child_a]
```

I would like to achieve something like this

```
child_a.pets.append(pet_a)
parent_a.children.append(child_a)
# commit/persist data
parent_a.children.all() # [child_a]
parent_a.pets.all() # [pet_a], because pet_a gets 
                    # automatically added to parent using some sorcery
                    # like for child in parent_a.children.all():
                    #     parent.pets.append(child.pets.all())
                    # or something like that.
```

I can achieve this with a method in the `Parent` object like `add_child_and_its_pets()`, but I would like to override the way relationship works, so I don't need to override other modules that may benefit from this behaviour, like `Flask-Admin` for instance.

Basically how should I override the `backref.append` method or the `relationship.append` method to also append other objects from other relationships at call time i.e. on the python side? How should I override the `remove` methods as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same answer from the [sqlalchemy mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/jgKgv5zQT7E), this can be achieved using [event listeners](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html), which are called before an `append` or `remove` is called on the object in the first parameter.

```
@db.event.listens_for(Parent.children, 'append')
def _append_children(parent, child, initiator):
    # appends also the pets bound to the child that the 
    # is being appended to the Parent

    parent.pets.extend(child.pets.all())

    # at the end of this call, executes
    # parent.children.append(child)
```

Answer (score 2):

For `parent.pets.all()`, I think you could use children as a [secondary join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins) condition, and treat it as an [associative entity or junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

It depends on your tables but that would look something like:

```
Parent.pets = relationship(
    Pet,
    backref='parent'
    primaryjoin=Pet.child_id == Child.id,
    secondaryjoin=Child.parent_id == Parent.id
)
```

You could also pretty reasonably make a backref `parent` if you so choose - this would let you access both `parent_a.pets` as well as `pet_a.parent`.

Comment: I'm reading about primaryjoin and secondaryjoin. In the meantime, what do you mean with "You could also pretty reasonably make a backref parent if you so choose." Could you provide an example?

Would it be necessary to show my code also?

Comment: Added the `backref` argument to show what that would look like. Does that help?