# symmetry in backref relationships not working as expected with event listeners

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, event-listener, relationships

I used to think that, in many to many relationships (perhaps for all of the relationships available)

```
parent.children.append(child)
```

and

```
child.parents.append(parent)
```

Were equivalent. I have, however, a rather *complex* set up which fires up event listeners for the *append* and *remove* methods of my classes.

This might be a long shot, but I have written a self contained example that explains my problem. In short, it contains:

- Three classes: `Parent`, `Child` and `Pet`. where

  - `Parent` has a many-to-many relationship with both `Child` and `Pet`
  - `Child` has a one-to-many relationship with `Pet`
- Three `event.listens_for` events

  - `@sa.event.listens_for(Parent.children, 'append')`
  - `@sa.event.listens_for(Parent.children, 'remove')`
  - `@sa.event.listens_for(Parent.pets, 'remove')`
- A test setup using `unittest`, with two tests:

  - `test_child_pet_relationship_on_parents_combined` test the appending of stuff from `Child`, like `child1.parents.append(test_parent)` where `child1` is an instance of `Child` and `test_parent` is an instance of `Parent`
  - `test_child_pet_relationship_on_parents_combined_reversed` does the same, but the other way around, like `test_parent.children.append(child1)`.
- A `logging` setup to log whatever is happening on each query. I have set some sloppy logger entries on each test and also in the first event listener. Namely, logs with `A` refer to the first test and `A'` refer to the second test.

asas

```
import logging
import sys

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base 

# setup logger
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(filename)s:%(lineno)d\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

Base = declarative_base()

# many to many relationship between parents and children
parents_children_relationship = sa.Table('parents_children_relationship',
    Base.metadata,
    sa.Column('parent_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('parents.id')),
    sa.Column('child_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('children.id')),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('parent_id', 'child_id'))

# many to many relationship between User and Pet
parents_pets_relationship = sa.Table('parents_pets_relationship',
    Base.metadata,
    sa.Column('parent_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('parents.id')),
    sa.Column('pet_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('pets.id')),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('parent_id', 'pet_id'))

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(64))

    # many to many relationship between parent and children
    # my case allows for a children to have many parents. Don't ask.
    children = sa.orm.relationship('Child',
                            secondary=parents_children_relationship,
                            backref=sa.orm.backref('parents', lazy='dynamic'),
                            lazy='dynamic')

    # many to many relationship between parents and pets
    pets = sa.orm.relationship('Pet',
                            secondary=parents_pets_relationship,
                            backref=sa.orm.backref('parents', lazy='dynamic'), #
                            lazy='dynamic')


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Parent (name=%r)>' % (self.name)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(64))
    # parents = <backref relationship with User model>

    # one to many relationship with pets
    pets = sa.orm.relationship('Pet', backref='child', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Child (name=%r)>' % (self.name)

class Pet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pets'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(64))
    # child = backref relationship with cities
    child_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('children.id'), nullable=
True)
    # parents = <relationship backref from User>

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Pet (name=%r)>' % (self.name)


from sqlalchemy.orm import object_session

@sa.event.listens_for(Parent.children, 'append')
def _on_append_children(parent, child, initiator):
    """
    If a new child is appended to the parent, this listener
    will also add the pets bound to the child being bound to the parent.
    """
    # appends also the pets bound to the child that the 
    # parent is being appended to

    logger.debug(f'**********1. adding the pets of {child} to {parent}***************')

    object_session(parent).execute(
        "INSERT INTO parents_pets_relationship VALUES "
        "(:parent_id, :pet_id)",
        [
            {"parent_id": parent.id, "pet_id": pet.id}
            for pet in child.pets
        ]
    )

    logger.debug('**********1. done!***************')


@sa.event.listens_for(Parent.children, 'remove')
def _on_remove_children(parent, child, initiator, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    If a child is removed from the parent, this listener
    will also remove only remove_single_pet --> <Pet>
    """

    object_session(parent).execute(
        "DELETE FROM parents_pets_relationship WHERE "
        "parent_id=:parent_id AND pet_id=:pet_id",
        [
            {"parent_id": parent.id, "pet_id": pet.id}
            for pet in child.pets
        ]
    )


@sa.event.listens_for(Parent.pets, 'remove')
def _on_remove_pets(parent, pet, initiator, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    If a pet is removed from the parent, and the parent also is related
    to the child that has access to that pet, then

    * removes relationship with the child, and
    * keeps relationship with the remaining pets, except the one that was 
removed
    """

    object_session(parent).execute(
        "DELETE FROM parents_children_relationship WHERE "
        "parent_id=:parent_id AND child_id=:child_id",
        {"parent_id": parent.id, "child_id": pet.child.id}
    ) 

#### test ###

import unittest
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

class BasicTestModelCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()


    def tearDown(self):
        Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=self.engine)

    def test_child_pet_relationship_on_parents_combined(self):
        """
        Test that a parent can be hold children and pets that don't
        belong necessary to the child, given the behaviour tested in the 
        previous test.
        """

        # create new parent
        test_parent = Parent(name='test_parent')

        child1 = Child(id=1,
                        name='FakeChild1')

        child2 = Child(id=2,
                        name='FakeChild2')

        pet1 = Pet(id=1,
                    name='FakePet1',
                    child_id=1)

        pet2 = Pet(id=2,
                    name='FakePet2',
                    child_id=2)

        pet3 = Pet(id=3,
                    name='FakePet3',
                    child_id=1)

        self.session.add(test_parent)
        self.session.add(child1)
        self.session.add(child2)
        self.session.add(pet1)
        self.session.add(pet2)
        self.session.add(pet3)
        self.session.commit()

        # add parent to the child
        logger.debug('************A - add test_parent to child1***************')
        child1.parents.append(test_parent)
        self.session.add(child1)
        self.session.commit()
        logger.debug('**********A - done!***************')

        # add parent to the child
        pet2.parents.append(test_parent)
        logger.debug('************B - add test_parent to child1***************')

        # persist changes in the db
        self.session.add(pet2)
        self.session.commit()
        logger.debug('**********B - done!***************')

        print(test_parent.pets.all())
        print(child2.pets.all())

        # check that previous relationships are intact
        self.assertTrue(child1.pets.all() == [pet1, pet3])
        self.assertTrue(child2.pets.all() == [pet2])

        # resultant elements should be only child1, its pets and the single Pet
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.children.all() == [child1])
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.pets.all() == [pet1, pet2, pet3])

        # remove child from parent
        logger.debug('***********C - remove test_parent from pet3****************')
        pet3.parents.remove(test_parent) ## ERROR here
        logger.debug('**********C - done!***************')

        # resultant elements should be remaining pets, and no child
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.children.all() == [])
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.pets.all() == [pet1, pet2]) # pet2 was not touched, 
                                                                # but pet1 should remain 
                                                                # since only                                                                 
                                                                # pet3 was removed                                                                
                                                                # child1 should be also removed since                                                                 
                                                                # relationship is unbalanced, i.e.                                                                
                                                                # user can't have access to a child if it                                                                
                                                                # does not have access to all of the child's pets

    def test_child_pet_relationship_on_parents_combined_reversed(self):
        """
        Test that a parent can hold children and pets that don't
        belong necessary to the child.
        """

        # create new parent
        test_parent = Parent(name='test_parent')

        child1 = Child(id=1,
                        name='FakeChild1')

        child2 = Child(id=2,
                        name='FakeChild2')

        pet1 = Pet(id=1,
                    name='FakePet1',
                    child_id=1)

        pet2 = Pet(id=2,
                    name='FakePet2',
                    child_id=2)

        pet3 = Pet(id=3,
                    name='FakePet3',
                    child_id=1)

        self.session.add(test_parent)
        self.session.add(child1)
        self.session.add(child2)
        self.session.add(pet1)
        self.session.add(pet2)
        self.session.add(pet3)
        self.session.commit()


        logger.debug('************A` - add child1 to test_parent***************')
        # add parent to the child
        test_parent.children.append(child1)
        self.session.add(test_parent)
        self.session.commit()
        logger.debug('**********A` - done!***************')


        logger.debug('************B` - add pet2 to test_parent***************')
        # add parent to the child
        test_parent.pets.append(pet2)

        # persist changes in the db
        self.session.add(test_parent)
        self.session.commit()
        logger.debug('**********B` - done!***************')

        # check that previous relationships are intact
        self.assertTrue(child1.pets.all() == [pet1, pet3])
        self.assertTrue(child2.pets.all() == [pet2])

        # resultant elements should be only child1, its pets and the single Pet
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.children.all() == [child1])
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.pets.all() == [pet1, pet2, pet3])

        # remove child from parent
        logger.debug('***********C` - remove pet3 from test_parent****************')
        test_parent.pets.remove(pet3) 
        logger.debug('**********C` - done!***************')

        # resultant elements should be remaining pets, and no child
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.children.all() == [])
        self.assertTrue(test_parent.pets.all() == [pet1, pet2]) # pet2 was not touched, 
                                                                # but pet1 should remain 
                                                                # since only                                                                 
                                                                # pet3 was removed                                                                
                                                                # child1 should be also removed since                                                                 
                                                                # relationship is unbalanced, i.e.                                                                
                                                                # user can't have access to a child if it                                                                
                                                                # does not have access to all of the child's pets



import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # # run tests
    unittest.main()
```

The first test passes, but the second does not. For the first test,

```
2018-05-21 11:52:50,646:pets2.py:195    DEBUG   ************A - add test_parent to child1***************
2018-05-21 11:52:50,648:base.py:682 INFO    BEGIN (implicit)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,649:base.py:1151    INFO    SELECT children.id AS children_id, children.name AS children_name 
FROM children 
WHERE children.id = ?
2018-05-21 11:52:50,649:base.py:1154    INFO    (1,)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,650:result.py:681   DEBUG   Col ('children_id', 'children_name')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,650:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (1, 'FakeChild1')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,652:base.py:1151    INFO    SELECT parents.id AS parents_id, parents.name AS parents_name 
FROM parents 
WHERE parents.id = ?
2018-05-21 11:52:50,652:base.py:1154    INFO    (1,)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,652:result.py:681   DEBUG   Col ('parents_id', 'parents_name')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,652:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (1, 'test_parent')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,652:pets2.py:91 DEBUG   **********1. adding the pets of <Child (name='FakeChild1')> to <Parent (name='test_parent')>***************
2018-05-21 11:52:50,654:base.py:1151    INFO    INSERT INTO parents_children_relationship (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (?, ?)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,654:base.py:1154    INFO    (1, 1)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,656:base.py:1151    INFO    SELECT pets.id AS pets_id, pets.name AS pets_name, pets.child_id AS pets_child_id 
FROM pets 
WHERE ? = pets.child_id
2018-05-21 11:52:50,656:base.py:1154    INFO    (1,)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,657:result.py:681   DEBUG   Col ('pets_id', 'pets_name', 'pets_child_id')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,657:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (1, 'FakePet1', 1)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,657:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (3, 'FakePet3', 1)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,658:base.py:1151    INFO    INSERT INTO parents_pets_relationship VALUES (?, ?)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,658:base.py:1154    INFO    ((1, 1), (1, 3))
2018-05-21 11:52:50,658:pets2.py:102    DEBUG   **********1. done!***************
2018-05-21 11:52:50,658:base.py:722 INFO    COMMIT
2018-05-21 11:52:50,659:pets2.py:199    DEBUG   **********A - done!***************
```

But for the second test, The logs and the error traceback is verbose, but the failing part is

```
2018-05-21 11:52:50,723:pets2.py:274    DEBUG   ************A` - add child1 to test_parent***************
2018-05-21 11:52:50,724:base.py:682 INFO    BEGIN (implicit)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,724:base.py:1151    INFO    SELECT children.id AS children_id, children.name AS children_name 
FROM children 
WHERE children.id = ?
2018-05-21 11:52:50,724:base.py:1154    INFO    (1,)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,725:result.py:681   DEBUG   Col ('children_id', 'children_name')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,725:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (1, 'FakeChild1')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,726:base.py:1151    INFO    SELECT parents.id AS parents_id, parents.name AS parents_name 
FROM parents 
WHERE parents.id = ?
2018-05-21 11:52:50,726:base.py:1154    INFO    (1,)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,726:result.py:681   DEBUG   Col ('parents_id', 'parents_name')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,727:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (1, 'test_parent')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,727:pets2.py:91 DEBUG   **********1. adding the pets of <Child (name='FakeChild1')> to <Parent (name='test_parent')>***************
2018-05-21 11:52:50,729:base.py:1151    INFO    INSERT INTO parents_children_relationship (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (?, ?)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,729:base.py:1154    INFO    (1, 1)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,731:base.py:1151    INFO    SELECT pets.id AS pets_id, pets.name AS pets_name, pets.child_id AS pets_child_id 
FROM pets 
WHERE ? = pets.child_id
2018-05-21 11:52:50,731:base.py:1154    INFO    (1,)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,731:result.py:681   DEBUG   Col ('pets_id', 'pets_name', 'pets_child_id')
2018-05-21 11:52:50,732:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (1, 'FakePet1', 1)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,732:result.py:1106  DEBUG   Row (3, 'FakePet3', 1)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,732:base.py:1151    INFO    INSERT INTO parents_pets_relationship VALUES (?, ?)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,732:base.py:1154    INFO    ((1, 1), (1, 3))
2018-05-21 11:52:50,733:pets2.py:102    DEBUG   **********1. done!***************
2018-05-21 11:52:50,735:base.py:1151    INFO    INSERT INTO parents_children_relationship (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (?, ?)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,735:base.py:1154    INFO    (1, 1)
2018-05-21 11:52:50,735:base.py:702 INFO    ROLLBACK
```

Based on the logger calls, "*something*" is happening **after** the event listener for `Parent.children.append` is finished and **before** `pet2.parents_pets.append(test_parent)` is called. This results in a row in the association table twice, why is this happening?

The specific error traceback from the test is

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: parents_children_relationship.parent_id, parents_children_relationship.child_id [SQL: 'INSERT INTO parents_children_relationship (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (1, 1)]
```

This question is related to

[override relationship behaviour in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031376/override-relationship-behaviour-in-sqlalchemy/50031564?noredirect=1#comment87121063_50031564)

And also to the same question in the Sqlalchemy's mailing list

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/jgKgv5zQT7E

I know is a lot to process, but I wonder why is this relationship not working symmetrically i.e why is one test passing but the other is not?

Thanks!

EDIT:

If I replace the event listener for one that listens on the *counterpart* `append` method (that is, the method for the Class that is the other side in the many to many relationship), for something like

```
@sa.event.listens_for(Child.parents_children, 'append')
def _on_append_children(child, parent, initiator):
    """
    If a new child is appended to the parent, this listener
    will also add the pets bound to the child being bound to the parent.
    """
    # appends also the pets bound to the child that the 
    # parent is being appended to

    logger.debug(f'**********1. (reversed) Adding the pets of {child} to {parent}***************')

    object_session(child).execute(
        "INSERT INTO parents_pets_relationship VALUES "
        "(:parent_id, :pet_id)",
        [
            {"parent_id": parent.id, "pet_id": pet.id}
            for pet in child.pets
        ]
    )

    logger.debug('**********1. done!***************')
```

Then *the first test fails and the second passes*, which kinda isolates the issue at the `listeners`, and probably related to the `object_session` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SQLAlchemy's mailing list (I edited it for context, credits to @zzzeek for his patience and help!)

> the issue is because the addition of test_parent to child1.parents
>   triggers two individual "dirty" events, which each resolve to the same
>   INSERT operation into the parents_children_relationship table.
>   Normally, these two dirty events are resolved together during the
>   flush process. However, within your "insert" event handler, calling
>   upon the "child.pets" collection, since it is a dynamic relationship,
>   triggers autoflush.  So, the first dirty event for parent being
>   appended to child is handled, the row is inserted within autoflush.
>   then your event completes.  then the backref handler goes off and
>   appends child to parent, triggering the second dirty event.   the
>   session.commit() then tries to flush the same thing a second time
>   which fails.
>
> the solution is to not flush within the event handlers.
>
> ```
> sess = object_session(parent)
> with sess.no_autoflush:
>     sess.execute(
>         "INSERT INTO parents_pets_relationship VALUES "
>         "(:parent_id, :pet_id)",
>         [
>             {"parent_id": parent.id, "pet_id": pet.id}
>             for pet in child.pets
>         ]
>     )
> ```

Changing this part on the listeners make both tests pass